# mdate() function codeigniter - error

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime, timestamp

In my database I have a `datetime` format row.

I wanna display the date on my codeigniter application in a more **human** way so I'm using the `mdate()` function. See more **[here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/helpers/date_helper.html)**.

But I get a PHP error:

> A non well formed numeric value encountered

I don't understand what is the problem.

MySQL query return the date as a string. Isn't the good format for the `mdate()` function?

I tried to change the date format in my database to `timestamp` but it didn't change anything.

Any ideas?

Here is my model:

```
public function get_online_labs()
{
    $conditions = array('online'=>1, 'type'=>'lab');
    $query = $this->db->select('id, title, date_start, description, online, type, face_pic')
                    ->from($this->table)
                    ->where($conditions)
                    ->order_by('date_start', 'desc')
                    ->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

My controler:

```
public function laboratories($id_lab = NULL)
{
    $data['datestring'] = "%D-%m-%Y - %h:%i %a";

    if (!$id_lab) {
        $this->load->helper('text');
        $data["labs"]=$this->eventsManager->get_online_labs();
        $this->load->template("site/laboratories_view", $data);
    }
    else {

    }
}
```

And the view:

```
<?php foreach ($labs as $lab) {?>
<div class="card list">
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('events/laboratories/'.$lab->id)?>"></a>
    <h2><?php echo $lab->title;?></h2>
    <p class="date"><?php echo mdate($datestring, $date)?></p>
    <img alt="<?php echo $lab->title.' promotional image'?>" src="<?php echo site_url($lab->face_pic)?>" />
    <p><?php echo word_limiter($lab->description, 50)?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. 

Can you show us some example code?

Comment: Thanks Hashem Qolami.
I formated my SQL timestamp date with the mysql_to_unix() function and it works!

Answer (score -1):

mdate() helper function accept two parameters, the first parameter is the Date string and the second one is the timestamp which is a integer.

Maybe CI-v3.0 documentation could explain that better: [hashem.ir/CodeIgniter/helpers/date_helper.html#mdate](http://hashem.ir/CodeIgniter/helpers/date_helper.html#mdate) –

Courtesy - Hashem Qolami